# Django and Markdown files: My media files aren't showing up in blog posts

Tags: django, django-templates, markdown, django-staticfiles

This is strange for me. Im working on a Markdown-based django-static-blog, but I cannot serve any static files on my markdown text from my static files. Django can serve my CSS/HTML/JS files, and it can even refer to any images for my blog posts, but when I am using django-markdown or Markdown 2.6.2 they dont show up. I even hard code the relative path to the picture and it still doesn't show up. This is how I set up my site:

**settings.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/this.static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "ve_static_root")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "this.static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "this.media"),
    # '/var/www/static/',
)
MEDIA_URL = '/this.media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "ve_media_root")
```

**urls.py** (after listing my urls)

```
# For development environment
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**My project tree**

```
(MYVirtualEnv) C:\Users\Jay_000\siteProject\PROJECTnew>tree
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows8_OS
Volume serial number is 00000068 5E7F:55B1
C:.
├───blog
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───PROJECTnew_config
│   └───__pycache__
├───templates
├───this.media
│   └───images
│       ├───blog
│       ├───figs
│       │   ├───2009-05-30-Google-charts
│       │   ├───2010-06-17-PCA-in-Gretl
│       │   ├───2012-01-19-Correspondence-Analysis
│       │   ├───2011-10-19-Dendrograms
│       │   ├───2012-11-13-MCR
│       │   ├───2012-12-04-My-Great-Porch
│       │   ├───2013-12-20-knitr
│       │   └───2014-09-11-Computer-Analysis
│       ├───gwdr
│       ├───eca
│       ├───r
│       └───this_test_site
└───this.static
    ├───css
    ├───fonts
    ├───img
    └───js
```

So, as you can see, I have two static file folders: one for web-design, and the other for image/video uploads. I cant even think about uploading videos if I cannot succeed in uploading pictures. **For the record:**

- The media file directories do work, *but only when I'm not using
  `django-markdown` or `Markdown`*. I tested the template filters on my home
  page, which doesnt have a Markdown overlay, and it shows up.
- The only thing that does show up is that little thumbnail picture which indicates that ***there was supposed to be a picture there, but its not showing up for some odd reason***
- Http URL paths work in the markdown files

After realizing that I figured that there is something else that Im missing, but I dont know where to start. I am not really strong in this area, but may this have something to do with inlinepatterns? From what I looked up, they seem to have something to do with images, but I am unsure. Either way, I would like a solution to this problem. Why aren't my staticfiles working with my Markdown rendered-posts?

Any kinds of suggestions regarding this issue would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show an example of the markdown text that isn't working, and the rendered html for that text.

Comment: I'm assuming this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/424) is related. As stated there, you can't have template syntax inside Markdown files (unless you are explicitly running the Markdown files through the template engine yourself). However, with the static full paths (sans template code), we need to see both the Markdown text and the HTML that is being output (as @Alasdair mentions) to help you.